# How do you reset an application's state in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I've used 
`App.reset()`
when doing Ember tests to reset the state of my application.

Is that the same function you would use in an existing application to reset the state?

I have an complex order form and when a technician successfully completes the form I want them to click a button that brings them back to the beginning so they can start another order.  I need to reset all my controller, route and model configurations.

I'm curious if there is a better way beyond `App.reset()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the store.unloadAll(type) - where type is the model type.

For example:

```
store.unloadAll('order');
```

Comment: And what about properties in the controller?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238860/how-can-clear-form-data-in-ember-js